# trying to cover multiple redirect conditions in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to code an htaccess file that covers all the bases that I need, but I have a lot of quite specific actions to cover.

I have three domains: .com .co.uk and .london and I want all traffic to end up at https://www.somepage.com except any traffic to .London, which has to be redirected to a specific mysite/London.php page

So all my conditions are:

```
force www prefix
force https
remove extensions
force .co.uk to .com domain
force any .london traffic to specific /london page
```

So far I have:

```
# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

So I need to add the last two conditions

```
force .co.uk to .com domain
force any .london traffic to specific /london page
```

But I am having difficulty getting everything to work together.

EDIT:

Still struggling with getting all conditions to work together, so adding some examples here for clarity.

www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

http://example.com -> https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com/mypage.php -> https://www.example.com/mypage

www.example.co.uk -> https://www.example.com

http://www.example.co.uk -> https://www.example.com

http://www.example.co.uk/mypage.php -> https://www.example.com/mypage

www.example.london -> https://www.example.com/london

http://example.london -> https://www.example.com/london

http://example.london/anything -> https://www.example.com/london

So ALL URLS must end up with 'www' added, .com domain only, https forced, php extension removed.

I have tried literally hundreds of code snippets and combinations, but cant get all conditions to work at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules :

```
# force .co.uk to .com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?\.example\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# force any .london traffic to specific /london page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.london$
# this line is important to avoid Redirect loop error
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/london/page
RewriteRule ^ /london/page%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```